# Apache2 virtualhost configuration trouble

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

This is my situation:

I have Redmine and Gitlab in my server which does not have a domain associated, because I will use the server IP address.

I want to configure two virtualhosts in apache2 with SSL in order to serve the above web applications, so I can access them like this:

```
https://x.y.z/redmine
```

which is located in /var/www/

```
https://x.y.z/gitlab
```

located in /home/git/github/public

I have configured apache by enabling two files in site-enabled: github.vhost and gitlab.vhost. The problem is that I cannot set gitlab to be accessible with

```
https://x.y.z/github
```

but only in

```
https://x.y.z
```

probably beacuse I do not use a domain but only the IP address of the server, and I don't know exactly how to manage it.

I would need some suggestion on how to correctly set the two vhost files.

Any suggestion?

Comment: This is my apachectl -S out http://pastebin.com/ShgYHG3h

Comment: "Pastebin.com is under heavy load right now :(". 
You do not need vhosts for this. Vhosts are for "virtual hosts", not IPs.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need separate virtualhost entries for this, you use the `Alias` directive to map another directory into the URL namespace of your existing (default) virtualhost.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName example.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
   Alias /redmine/ /var/www/redmine/
   Alias /gitlab/ /home/git/github/public/
</Virtualhost>
```